# How to catch a 3rd party JS event to modify its action?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, zurb-foundation

How to catch a 3rd party JS event to modify its action ?

My example is i have set a stickybar on my website using foundation.

```
<div data-sticky="xrwv5y-sticky" class="toc-desktop toc toc-tree sticky is-anchored is-at-top" data-top-anchor="main:top" data-btm-anchor="main:bottom" data-resize="49dgxp-sticky" data-mutate="49dgxp-sticky" style="max-width: 288.567px; margin-top: 0px; bottom: auto; top: 0px;" data-events="mutate"><h2 class="heading">Sommaire</h2><ol class="circle">...
```

When scrolling down, the JS from foundation apply a different margin-top on the is-stuck class

```
<div data-sticky="xrwv5y-sticky" class="toc-desktop toc toc-tree sticky is-at-top is-stuck" data-top-anchor="main:top" data-btm-anchor="main:bottom" data-resize="49dgxp-sticky" data-mutate="49dgxp-sticky" style="max-width: 288.567px; margin-top: 1em; bottom: auto; top: 0px;" data-events="mutate"><h2 class="heading">Sommaire</h2><ol class="circle"><li><a href="#pararaph-header-730">
```

I would like to modify this behaviour to add some px to the margin-top depending if the top admin toolbar is displayed or not

Comment: You can try to override the base styles using the same class. But for a more general understanding, can you share a practical example?

Comment: this is the practical ex https://get.foundation/sites/docs/sticky.html . if u watch the class sticky of the milky way picture , you will see that a margin top is applied in JS when u scroll . On a custom JS file i would like to catch that event and ovveride it to change the margin top value

Comment: did you try to use data-margin-top property? https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/GmGbjK